# Multiple users updating XML file with AJAX/PHP

Tags: php, xml, ajax

I am working on a script for judges of a film festival to review and vote for films. I was thinking I could minimize the project by saving all the results in a single XML file. My concern however is if multiple judges are casting their vote at the same time, will there be a conflict with the XML file being written to at the same time?

Here is my thought on a schema :

```
<festival>
<teams>
    <team id='*'>
        <name></name>
        <video>http://vimeo.com/####</video>
        <ratings>
            <judge id='%'>(1-7)</judge>
        </ratings>
        <nominations>
            <judge id='%'>@</judge>
        <nominations>
    </team>
</teams>
<awards>
    <award id='@'>Best Director</award>
</awards>
<judges>
    <judge id='%'>
        <name></name>
        <email></email>
        <password></password>
        <lastVideoWatched></lastvideowatched>
    </judge>
</judges>
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay first of all,

Why are you using xml files? It would be much easier to use a database for this sort of thing. Even mysqli will work quite well. You can use simple xml to parse the file and save it in memory before committing, but I see no way of doing it concurrently. But I cannot see anyway of doing concurrent transactions without building an engine in the middle.

IF you'll take my advice, switch to mysql